# Django. Are these two queries the same?

Tags: django, django-queryset

First. I am not sure how to write this question so it would be more useful to SO users, maybe someone could edit the question.

So, I have these two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
   foreign = models.Foreignkey(A)
   aproperty = models.CharField(...)
```

And I have these two possibilities of a query in a view:

```
b_objs = B.objects.filter(aproperty=value)
a_objs = [b.foreign for b in b_objs]

or

a_objs = A.objects.filter(b__aproperty=value)
```

Are they equally expensive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not only "not equally expensive", but the result is also different.

First approach: You query directly on `B`, then get all `foreign` by looping on `b_objs`. Result is a list.

Second approach: You did a database `join` operation in the underline implementation, then fetch the results. Result is a queryset.

Apparently the second approach is more efficient, because you only joined the database once to fetch the result, whereas the first approach you need to hit the database many times to get `A` objects.

Comment: You could use ```B.obejcts.filter(aproperty=value).select_related('foreign')``` to reduce it to one database query, though without any other assumptions, I'd still go with the second approach.

Comment: Maybe you should say explicitly that in the first approach you are going to hit the database as many objects there are in `b_objs`. To fetch each `a` a select is used.

Comment: @schillingt Tried the `select_related` query many times, it doesn't work.

Comment: @alejoss: What's not working? Can you describe in details? Django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: @schillingt nevermind, thanks for the `select_related` comment. I thought select_related would populate the query with A objects. It populates it with B objects that already contain the related A objects.